# Installation of Linux distro on Mac Pro Model A1211 circa 2006

Tags: boot, mac

I was given a Mac Book Pro Model A1211, T7400 version 2.2. Currently running mac os X Lion 10.7.5 How do I create a Boot DVD or USB to perform a "fresh install" of Ubuntu, Linux Mint, etc. Any assistance you can render would be appreciated. I am a PC guy with limited experience with Linux.

Comment: And please use an official Ubuntu if you want assistance from askubuntu users.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand, please advise

Comment: we do not support Linux. we are limited to official Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Would someone assist me if I downloaded a copy of Ubuntu 20.0.4?

Comment: I can help. Do you know how much memory is installed? If you want to install a 64 bit version, then you need to install to BIOS boot. This is because you have a 32 bit EFI. You probably can not use a DVD to install the current release. To boot the 64 bit installer, you will have to first install a BIOS booting 32 bit version of Linux. You can then use Grub to boot the 64 bit installer. Anyway, if interested in a more detailed explanation, post a comment. Also, you may want to post your question at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The system has 4GB of ram. And yes, more detailed explanation would be awesome.

Comment: Note: You should put @DavidAnderson in your comment, otherwise I might not get notified. You probably will need to post a new question in order for me to post an answer. Try to include that you need instructions for installing the current version of 64 bit Ubuntu LTS on a 2006 Mac with 64 bit processors, but a 32 bit EFI. Having 4 GB for ram means you can install the current 64 bit Ubuntu.